# Programmatically grant new versions of my application access to camera and microphone

Tags: security, mojave

I have remote machines running my software. I have full control with MDM.
I run a video conference application and need access to the camera and microphone.

Every time I push a new version of the software I have to manually approve access to the webcam. Is there something I can do in my install script (maybe with defaults write) to allow access to the webcam?